# eclipse throwing swt errror when adding a server

Tags: eclipse, swt

Eclipse swt error while adding a server. I am using ubuntu 16.04. This error does not occur if I use 2019 eclipse version. Is this error related to gtk ?

[image]

[image]
emphasized text

[image]

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Error while reading from repository: http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/library/oracle-maf-2.3.3-examples/site.xml.

Comment: !MESSAGE Unexpected error loading extension: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.simpleRepository
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.<init>(ServiceTracker.java:187)
 at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.<init>(ServiceTracker.java:250)

Comment: @user1887464 Please add the log starting with `!SESSION` to your question formatted as _Code Sample_ instead of adding snippets of it as comments that are hard to read. Please also tell the GTK version you have on Linux.

Comment: log is too big for the comment, is there any way I can share the file with you ?

Comment: libgtk-3-0:amd64           
   3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3   amd64

Comment: [edit] your question to add the log

Comment: hey, I was able to solve the issue by, updating ubuntu. Apparently gtk was updated to 3.20 and now I don't face any errors. Thanks a tone.